# Как сделать проверку формы авторизации, данные которой получаю через ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, mvc

Пытаюсь сделать проверку формы авторизации и хочу реализовать такую логику: если поле $_POST['login'] совпадает с значением из файла json (в моем случае Admin), то мы переходим в cabinet.
Но пока застопорился в плане логики, ведь исходя из прошлых заданных мною вопросов я понял, что не смогу просто так получить желаемый $_POST['login'], + дело до foreach скорее всего не дойдет, так как $_POST пустой. Подскажите, как можно решить данную проблему?

Ниже код:
**Файл IndexController.php**

```
//обработчик формы
    public function ajax_signin() {
        $result = array(
            'login' => $_POST["login"],
            'password' => md5($_POST["password"])
        );
        $json = json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); //флаг для Кириллицы
        echo $json;
    }
//метод, в котором я пытаюсь проверить данные
    public function index() {
        $this->pageData['title'] = "Вход в личный кабинет";
        $data = file_get_contents('test.json');
        $data = json_decode($data, true);
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        foreach ($data as $value) {
            foreach ($value as $key => $item) {
                if ($key == '0' && $_POST['login'] == $item) {

                    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['login'];
                    header("Location: cabinet");
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
        $this->view->render($this->pageTpl, $this->pageData);
    }
```

**Файл lib.js**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#signinbutton").click(
        function(){
            sendAjaxForm('result_form', 'form__signin', 'Index/ajax_signin');
            return false;
        }
    );
});

function sendAjaxForm(result_form, ajax_form, url) {
    $.ajax({
        url:     url, //url страницы (action_ajax_form.php)
        type:     "POST", //метод отправки
        dataType: "html", //формат данных
        data: $("#"+ajax_form).serialize(),  // Сеарилизуем объект
        success: function(response) { //Данные отправлены успешно
            result = $.parseJSON(response);
            //$('#result_form').html('Имя: '+result.login+'<br>Пароль: '+result.password);
            //window.location.href = "cabinet";
        },
        error: function(response) { // Данные не отправлены
            $('#result_form').html('Ошибка. Данные не отправлены.');
        }
    });
}
```

**Файл test.json**

{"0":{"0":"Admin","1":"e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e","2":"test@gmail.com","3":"Иван"}}

Comment: В итоге не ясно в чём именно проблема

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в том, что не срабатывает мой header если $_POST['login'] == $item. Не могу понять как сделать чтобы это заработало. Данные файла json в индексе считываются корректно, $item отображается корректно, но вот проверка не работает.

Comment: Я до сих пор не понимаю: __почему__ ты думаешь, что при вызове урла __Index/ajax_signin__ и соответствующего `ajax_signin()` как-то откуда-то сработает `index()`?

Comment: @u_mulder просто если расскоментить строку //$('#result_form').html('Имя: '+resul ... в lib.js, данные отображались в форме, и у меня появился лучик надежды что мне удалось их получить. Не подскажете  как в моем случае сделать правильно?

Comment: В твоем случае логику авторизации надо разместить в методе `ajax_signin()`. Либо сабмитить форму на тот же самый `index`.

Comment: @u_mulder не додумался до этого, спасибо! Буду ковырять дальше) И извиняюсь что вам приходится читать мои глупые вопросы, сам понимаю какой бред пишу, но хочу выполнить задуманное